# Unable to resize images

Tags: support

I am no longer able to resize images on the site, previously I'd used the methods outlined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25051) but unfortunately they seem not be working anymore at least for me.

Is there any way to reduce images size of large images on the site?

Comment: I've noticed that, too. My guess is it's an issue on Imgur's end. Except for downloading the image, resize it "physically" and upload the resized image, I don't think there's anything that can be done from SE's end. Well, maybe wait until Imgur solved it. Or using the `b` instead of `m` – which still works, but results in a "squared image" … // Oh, and it's of course not restricted to Android.SE – so may I refer you to the "Main Meta": [The Stack Imgur service is no longer resizing images correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314028/192154)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Meta.StackExchange.Com. Not migrating it though as it's already there.

Comment: `[<img src="YOUR_IMG_LINK" width="292" height="555" alt="IMG: " title="">][]` can be used until than.